# how to trigger a function call after first function finishes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

I am working with Backbone.js and I am in a condition where I have a primary function call, `this.search.searchGoogle(searchTerm)`, that triggers other function calls. However, the next line after my primary function call is another function call, `this.search.cleanView`,. The problem is that sometimes the second call gets called before the primary function is complete.

```
   addNewPlace: function(e) {

      var searchTerm = this.$el.find("input").val();
      var poi = new vrboPoi({
        title: searchTerm,
        lat: this.options.vrbo_place.lat,
        lng: this.options.vrbo_place.lng
      });


      var target = $(e.target),
           index = target.closest("ul.pois").children().index(target.parent())
      this.search = new match({
        model: poi
      });

      this.search.render();

      this.search.searchGoogle(searchTerm);           
      this.search.bind("place:selected", this.placeSelected, this);

      // setTimeout( 
      //   this.search.cleanView, 500 
      //  );
      e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Is there a way to prevent `this.search.cleanView` from being called until `this.search.searchGoogle(searchTerm)` is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if its async. You will have to make `searchGoogle` take a callback or raise an event.

Comment: Another option is to use jQuery promises/Deferred objects. [link](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)